# Javascript on scroll event change css then wait and then rechange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the css on scroll event and it is working.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".navcont").css("background-color", "pink")
});
```

But, when I try to give delay and change it back,

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".navcont").css("background-color", "pink")
        .delay( 5000 )
        .css("background-color", "white");
});
```

It always shows pink color, But I want the white color first then delay and then pink color.

Can some one help me with this!
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to use 80000? That's 1 minute and 20 seconds..

Comment: sorry for that, I was just trying to see if the pink will show up or not. I do not want delay in minutes only 5 or 10 seconds it fine.

Comment: no it is not working! that's why I increase it in the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using only `setTimeout`, without `animate`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".navcont").css("background-color", "pink");
    setTimeout(function() {$(".navcont").css("background-color", "white")}, 8000);
});
```

Here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUa7S/2/).

Comment: Hey, thanks works exactly I wanted it to be, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

First thing I think of is using `.animate()` to get the callback, then using `setTimeout` to delay the return to CSS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.navcont').animate({backgroundColor:'pink'},1,function(){
        var $this = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.css({backgroundColor:'white'});
            },80000);
    });
});
```

The `1` means the animation is 1 millisecond long, which is invisible to the eye but I've had issue with using zero so I just add a value to satisfy the callback.

Comment: I tried this but, still I can see only white color. I increased `1` to some seconds also to see pink but it is not coming up!

Answer (score 0):

The delay() function works only on a [jQuery effects queue](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), not on all functions. The effects are such as fadeIn, slideUp, etc. There is a custom effect generator called animate() and you can use that with delay(). However, you cannot animate non-numeric properties like background-color. So here is a trick -

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".navcont")
    .animate({dummyProperty: "dummyValue"},1,"linear",function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","pink")
    })
    .delay( 80000 )
    .animate({dummyProperty: "dummyValue"},1,"linear",function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","blue")
    });
});
```

1. The first argument for animate is a css property you wish to animate. Since background-color cannot be animated, we use a dummy property here (you can use anything here, doesn't make any difference).
2. The second argument is the time of animation. We just use 1 millisecond here because we set the real delay using the delay() function.
3. The third argument is the easing (doesn't matter in this case).
4. The fourth argument is a callback function with 'this' pointing to the selected HTML element. So we change it's background-color here.